# Increased capacity purchased on iCloud isn't available for photos

Tags: icloud, photos

I signed up to the standard 5GB iCloud plan when I purchased my iPhone 6. Just a few days back was advised I needed to increase iCloud capacity to receive more photos. I have paid to increase to 50GB, and this now shows as available storage. However, I still cannot upload photos into this increased storage.

Does the extra capacity have to be activated? I've signed up for a monthly billing. Do I have to wait for this to happen? Surely this is covered by iTunes payment setup. Has anyone else had the same problem, and if so how to fix?

Comment: Might this be the same as the linked question? Please edit your question if not so with some details.